# PHP - Problems displaying information once user has signed in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I had this working a few days ago, but I cannot seem to get the session ID to display on screen once the user has signed into their account. I have two PHP which I've been working on and I've checked both for errors using checkers online and come up short with nothing. So with what's below, once the user has signed in, it will display their session ID inside the site's header, but even though I am correctly signing in (I've checked it's logging in with my database), all it does it display "You are not logged in!".

Login.inc.php

```
    <?php
    include '../dbh.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd   = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND pwd='$pwd'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "You are not signed in!";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    }
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    ?>
```

site_header.php

```
<head>
    <?php
        session_start();
       ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,300,200italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>iBPBuyer</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.php">SIGN UP</a></li>
            <?php
               echo "<form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='E-Mail'>
                    <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
                    <button type='submit'>Login</button>
                </form>";
               ?>
            <?php
               if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                   echo $_SESSION['id'];
               } else {
                   echo "You are not logged in!";
               }
               ?>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
```

Comment: put  `session_start()` in the begining of your php script

Comment: @Ayaou, I accidentally cut that out of the code script that I posted, but it is on top of the site_header.php file

Comment: @BenParry Is it in login?

Comment: Also, use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just want to be echoing stuff out. I would recommend using an authenticated flag

```
<?php
include '../dbh.php';

session_start(); //THIS APPEARS TO BE MISSING 

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd   = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //You have Session no matter what for this user
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = false;
} else {
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}
header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

Then in your view you can do this

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['authenticated']) {
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
} else {
    echo "You are not logged in!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the   `header("Location: ../index.php");` befor you send or echo anything.

Since the header was sent with the `echo "You are not logged in"` therefore it connot send another header saying to redirect.

Workaround would eb to skip the echo, or use Js to redirect your user.

```
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php");

} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}
```

this would work

Alos further down, the same apply to session_start because it need to send the session cookie in header.

SO this head tag is also causing problem

```
<head>
    <?php
        session_start();
       ?>
```

Check your error log, i bet you have a header have already been sent wraning.

So in the end, you cannot send or echo anything before you start the session or use header(). Another work around is to use output buffer. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php